# Adding JSON metadata strings to a STEP file

Tags: json, step, eyeshot

I'm making use of DevDept's Eyeshot library to manage 3D graphics files which contain geometries that represent the parts of a metalcasting mold. Largely these are either basic Brep primitives or STL-file type imports, combined into one scene.

Each geometry is associated with thermal properties for use in the simulator. If I use STEP as an export format, I'd like to include the thermal properties as metadata, either as a separate custom entity with an index, either a number or string key, or the properties themselves.

In either case, the thermal properties are easy to express as a multiline JSON string.

Is it possible to include descriptive metadata like this in a STEP file? What would be a good approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

general "STEP" is not a format, it is a set of standards. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303

That means that you need to know which "AP" you are to use (depending). You then usually find some "recommended practices" or "usage guide"  done by association like PDES, Inc. and ProSTEP iViP, that explains how you can (and should) implement these standards.

Comment: OK, then... is your answer to the first question, "yes"?, and the second, "I don't know"? Since I'm approaching this entirely from an industry that understands STEP as a file format, not a set of standards... I described the data as "either basic Brep primitives or STL-file type imports." Which "AP" is that and where's the primer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303#Coverage_of_STEP_Application_Protocols_(AP)

Comment: That is not a primer for a topic this technical. Most of the pages are consigned to archive.org, and their links are broken. And it is not an answer to any of my questions.

Comment: Hi Rob, if you cannot precise basics such as the AP of STEP and the type of file (STEP-File / STEP-XML) you intent to use, I do not know who can help you.

Comment: As a software engineer, I'm very accustomed to reading standards documents, not encountering a paywall for the documents. But upon digging into it even further, there appear to be three distinct and different APs for my use case, an infinite number of ways to define custom data, and no settled schemas for even something as straightforward as IGES-format graphics. All well and good, but combined with the paywall, I can't see the point of ever supporting or customizing STEP in my software. I suppose that becomes the answer to my question.

Comment: I agree with you, STEP is really abstract and open. That's why some groups of implementors developed recommended practices and usage guides in order to understand them each other. I totally understand your point.

Comment: Abstract, open (? as a specification with extensible potential, yes, but not GNU kind of "open"), documented in a kind of Schlaer-Mellor government-planning way, and in a day when abstract and open data interchange is supportable by cost-free schemas, (XML and JSON come to mind)kind of understandable that it doesn't have a lot of mindshare I can tap. 

Well and good; this is the answer.

Comment: @RobPerkins, take a look at the open source project http://stepcode.org/. It also contains references to projects implementing/documenting STEP.